# Breadth-first search in Java: Competitive style - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, array, breadth-first-search

I have improved my [BFS in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219702/breadth-first-search-in-java-competitive-style) according to vnp's suggestions. Again, we wish to find shortest paths in directed unweighted graphs using BFS, competitive style (no `Map`s, `Set`'s or `List`s):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class BFS {

    static int[] bfs(int[][] graph, int sourceNode, int targetNode) {
        int[] queue = new int[graph.length];
        int[] parents = new int[graph.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
            parents[i] = -1; // -1 denotes 'not used'
        }

        int queueStartIndex = 0;
        int queueEndIndex = 1;

        queue[0] = sourceNode;
        parents[sourceNode] = -2;

        while (queueStartIndex < queueEndIndex) {
            int currentNode = queue[queueStartIndex++];

            if (currentNode == targetNode) {
                return buildPath(targetNode, parents);
            }

            for (int childNode : graph[currentNode]) {
                if (parents[childNode] == -1) {
                    parents[childNode] = currentNode;
                    queue[queueEndIndex++] = childNode;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static int[] buildPath(int targetNode, int[] parents) {
        int pathLength = 0;
        int node = targetNode;

        while (node >= 0) {
            pathLength++;
            node = parents[node];
        }

        int[] path = new int[pathLength];
        int pathIndex = path.length - 1;
        int currentNode = targetNode;

        while (currentNode >= 0) {
            path[pathIndex--] = currentNode;
            currentNode = parents[currentNode];
        }

        return path;
    }

    /*    B ----+
         /      |
        A       E
         \      /
          C - D
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 2;
        int d = 3;
        int e = 4;

        int[][] graph = new int[5][];
        graph[a] = new int[]{ c, b };
        graph[b] = new int[]{ e };
        graph[c] = new int[]{ d };
        graph[d] = new int[]{ c, e };
        graph[e] = new int[]{ b, d };

        // A -> B -> E
        int[] path = bfs(graph, a, e);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path));

        // A <- B <- E does not exist:
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bfs(graph, e, a)));

        graph = new int[4][];
        graph[a] = new int[]{ b, c };
        graph[b] = new int[]{ d };
        graph[c] = new int[]{ a, d };
        graph[d] = new int[]{ b, c };

        /*     B
              / \
             A   D
              \ /
               C
        */

        // A -> B -> D
        path = bfs(graph, a, d);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path));

        path = bfs(graph, d, a);
        // D -> C -> A:
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path));
    }    
}
```

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: is there any reason why you implement this code in java? one benefit of java is OOP and your code has not much Objects...

Comment: @MartinFrank (1) It's written in competition in mind where people have no time for implementing, say, graph node types, but instead represent them via simple `int` value.  (2) The above requires no Objects...

Comment: well, ok, if that is fine for you ... i don't understand that 'competitive style' yet, time to go back on my books...

Comment: @MartinFrank Google up in YouTube "acm icpc world finals 2018" ;)

Comment: thank you very very much on how to find that - googling 'competive style' was rather worthless !!!